# TexMaker gives "! Undefined control sequence. \AddToHook" error when trying to compile sample cv

Tags: texmaker, cv

I am trying to compile a sample CV from Overleaf on my TexMaker editor but I am getting an error:

> ! Undefined control sequence. \AddToHook

on line 424 of altacv.cls:

> \AddToHook{package/biblatex/after}{

This is the link to the tex files. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-template/trgqjpwnmtgv

I thought the error might be to do with the Tex version so I deleted and redownloaded Texmaker so I am now running the most recent 5.1.4 on Mac.

Comment: your texsystem is outdated and so can't use this class.

Comment: TeXmaker is just an editor, it's irrelevant that you've got the latest version. What matters is the version of the TeX distribution (macTeX, I guess), that's what you must update.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I will try to update my Tex version with Tex live.